# AttributeError: module 'sklearn.linear_model' has no attribute 'linearRegression'?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import math
rd=pd.read_csv('homeprices.csv')
a=rd.iloc[:-1]
median_bedrooms=math.floor(a.bedrooms.median())
median_bedrooms
rd.bedrooms=rd.bedrooms.fillna(median_bedrooms)
rd
reg=LinearRegression()
```

After this i'm getting an bellow error:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-a53be8969e13> in <module>
----> 1 reg=linear_model.linearRegression()

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.linear_model' has no attribute 'linearRegression'
```

How can i fix this bug now?

Comment: Your call is wrong, you already imported the class so use it like `reg=LinearRegression()`

Comment: i did but same error is comming again, Now what shall i do?

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall sklearn

Comment: i'm using pandas. sklearn is preinstalled in it.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall  refer this docs sklearn https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Comment: Works fine for me on my machine. Are you sure there are no typos etc?

Comment: i'm 100% sure..i checked 10 times each and every single line of code.

Comment: You don't have sklearn installed in your system , Your comment " I am using Pandas sklearn is preinstalled in it doesn't make any sense" See below for Pandas dependencies  and sklearn dependencies  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html can you reconfirm sklearn is installed

Comment: but i run the code above link that you provided is working correctly. but in my code is showing error ..how???

Comment: import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]])
# y = 1 * x_0 + 2 * x_1 + 3
y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
reg.score(X, y)     .......#This code is working finely

Comment: Please edit your question to include the example code that works well. Also, make sure to copy the traceback given from the code shown (the current traceback does not match the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but in your traceback you have

```
reg=linear_model.linearRegression()
```

This command does not appear anywhere in your question. Indeed, if this is what you wrote, it should be `LinearRegression`, not  `linearRegression`